# How does Bitmap sameAs work?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

The `Bitmap` (from android.graphics) has the `sameAs` method.
Given another bitmap, it returns true if it has the same dimensions, config, and pixel data as this bitmap.
I wonder how it works under the hood? Does it make sense to override it (maybe using some histogram method or keypoint matching)?

Answer (score 4):

It basically does

```
if(bmp1.height==bmp2.height && bmp1.width==bmp2.width) {
  for(int i=0; i< bmp1.width; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< bmp1.height; j++){
      if(bmp1.getPixel(i,j) != bmp2.getPixel(i,j)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
return false;
```

But it will use a low level memory comparison function like memcmp instead of actually looping like that.

As for does it make sense to override it-  not really.  You'd screw up anyone else who assumes the function works as is.  It may make sense to create your own function sameKeyPoint that does key point matching though.